# Google webpage translate - exit from translation mode, any method available?

Tags: google-translate

I'm using this URL for Google Translate on my website (let's say http://example.com) as a menu item:

```
https://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&sl=auto&tl=DE&u=http://example.com
```

After user goes on this page Google shows my website translated in `<iframe>`.
Since Google overwrites all links in this frame, user cannot go back on the untranslated page.
Is there any method to go back on the original page (http://example.com)?

Comment: These links has some solutions to achieve this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38873043/8090237

Comment: The method you linked above uses Google Translate JS API. It is actually not the same I mentioned in question.

Comment: I am looking for an answer to this myself +1